Armature imported as Empties, how to convert to Blender Armature?
I imported an armature from a model that I have. The model is from long ago, I had to do some conversion just to open it in Blender 4.2.3. For some reason, instead of coming in as an Armature object, each bone as an Empty object. Is there a way I can convert the Empties into an Armature?
I'm really new to the 3D world, modeling, and animation. If there is any route better than this, let me know plz.


Yes, I believe that would be possible, though I'm not sure how to do it outside the Python API. That might be the only way. I'll do some research and get back to you. BTW, what format was the model originally in? Was it from an old version of Blender, or something else?

Why did you only import the armature?

could you please share the file?

I could share the files, but is there anywhere I can upload and release it here ? It origin was a .fbx file from old blender, that I had to import o 3dmax 2010, and convert it to a new fbx verion to import it on blender 4.3.2

read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/

This addon will do the job, but it's paid. The free version does not have the orientation feature, but I already made basically the same thing in this non-addon script. So:

Use the free version of the addon to create an armature.
Open my script in Blender's text editor and follow its instructions starting at step 3:


3] Go into edit mode on the armature, and select all bones.

4] Run this script.

5] Double-check bones on the ends of chains, such as fingers and quills.

6] Enjoy, TYL!


